# Insert List In cassandra using astyanax

Tags: java, list, insert, cassandra, astyanax

I am facing a problem in Cassandra to insert list

```
create table employees(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar,
emails list <varchar>
);
```

CQL query

```
insert into employees (id, name, emails) values (1,'fake_name',['fake1@fake1.com', 'fake2@fake2.com']);
```

result of **select * from employees**

```
 id | emails                                | name
----+----------------------------------------+--------
 1 | ['fake1@fake1.com', 'fake2@fake2.com'] | shahid
```

How we can insert list using [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax) ?

Comment: @Crowie I insert this record using command line? now I want to insert in Java using Astyanax API. means I have a List i.e `List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>(); list.add("fake1@fake1.com"); list.add("fake2@fake2.com");` how to insert this list in Cassandra using Astyanax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert List in Cassandra using Astyanax with CQL3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268181/insert-list-in-cassandra-using-astyanax-with-cql3)

Comment: @Crowie can you answer any one of these two ?

Answer (score 1):

Astayanax is still based on the old Thrift API, so it is missing the underlying abstractions to support CQL collections like Lists.  You should use the CQL Java Driver instead: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver